# Use ajax-zoom without running php?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, 360-degrees

I want to use this great plugin in my project

https://www.ajax-zoom.com/index.php?cid=examples

but it seems that a php environment is required to run this plugin

can I use it in on javascript only(front-end only) environment?

If not, is there any alternative?

I want a 360 product spinner with zoom and hotspots supports

Comment: Why do you think this has a PHP dependency? jQuery has no dependency on a server sided language

Comment: You don't need to use PHP, Ajax-Zoom is a client side library. Just download the library and include it in your html page and follow the examples. 
You would need to use PHP if for example you want to retrieve the images from the server

Comment: Because when I call the axZm plugin, it always makes a request to /js/axZm/zoomLoad.php

Comment: @ErisoHV can you please provide a working demo that no using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

> You don't need to use PHP, Ajax-Zoom is a client side library. Just download the library and include it in your html page and follow the examples. You would need to use PHP if for example you want to retrieve the images from the server

I retract my previous answer, you actually need PHP scripts for the operation of this library. As indicated on the website:

> [Unlike most jQuery plugins, the options are set in the file zoomConfig.inc.php . **This is because the JavaScript and PHP options are both needed.**](https://www.ajax-zoom.com/index.php?cid=docs)

In addition, the documentation indicates that:

> Basic knowledge of HTML, CSS, PHP and JavaScript is usually necessary to get AJAX-ZOOM running. It is recommended to start with the supplied examples and to gradually adjust their source code to suit your needs.

I hope this clarifies your doubt